# How to view a photo marked up in iOS on my laptop ? (.AAE file)

Tags: iphone, photos

I've taken a couple of photos on my iPhone 5s running iOS 10 and annotated them using the built-in markup feature.

The photos look fine when viewed on the iPhone but when I transferred them to my laptop (MacBook Pro 15-inch, Mid 2012, running 10.10.5) via the Image Capture utility it imported all of the photos, but they where not marked up, instead for each photo I got an accompanying .AAE file, which I presume is the markup overlay.

How can I get the photo to save as a JPEG with the markup already overlaid ?

Comment: What is the year of your MBP?

Comment: @paper1111 - 15-inch, Mid 2012 (ive updated the question now to include it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS overlays the markup as saved in the .AAE file. Whenever you see the photo the markups will be overlaid.

**Solution 1**

When you send the photo to your MacBook Pro using **AirDrop**, a new image (the original image and the markup) will be generated on-the-fly and sent to your Mac with all markups intact.

For this to work you need a "MacBook Pro (Late 2008) or later, excluding the MacBook Pro (17-inch, Late 2008)". See [Apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106).

**Solution 2**

If you are not able to use AirDrop with your Mac, you may create a **Shared Photo album** with iOS' Photo.app. As soon as the shared image appears in the new album you can save it to your camera roll with all markups applied. Please note that the resolution of these photos will be reduced to fit 2048 px x 2048 px.

**Solution 3**

Use **Photos.app on your Mac**. If both the image file and the .AAE file are in the same folder they both get imported. You will see all markups applied in Photos.app.

To export an image with these markups applied just drag it to your Desktop or any other folder.

Comment: thanks @oa- is it possible to get it to work with image capture, ive had issues in the past with airdrop, with the phone not being able to find the laptop and visa versa. A shared album on Photos wouldnt work for us either unfortunatly as some people in our office use their personal phones, which they take work related photos on, then transfer them via Image Capture, which allows them to only select their work photos and not their personal photos.

Comment: If you import it with Photos.app all markups will be displayed just fine. From there you can drag any marked up photos to your Desktop or any other folder. This will create a PNG/JPG with all markups applied.